# How to feed Math node with a range of numbers?

Tags: python, shaders

Can't come up with how to supply a range of float numbers into the value input of the Math node?
Indeed, there is available to set a single float value
[image]

as well as to plug a bunch of data
[image]

I wonder how to plug a specific range of numbers like [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]?

[image]

Comment: You can't in the current design.  You have to have a compare for each unique value and then _or_ the compares together.  Since Blender doesn't have logic nodes, or can be accomplished by adding the output of two compares and clamping the result.

Comment: @MartyFouts But maybe there is a scripting solution, is it?

Comment: Alas, Blender doesn't export an interface to allow you to use scripts in material node trees.  You could write a tool that creates a node group from an array using the technique I described, but you'd have to add the node group where you wanted it manually.

Comment: Sadness, anyway thank you